# Module: local variable specification error

Tags: vector, scoping

I am developing a module which does some vector algebra, and I have added an image of the code in the link below. (I did not find a good way to add formatted code in this pane). If the image resolution is not good, I will re-try adding code the proper way. 
    This module worked fine in the course of the development, but somewhere along the path, I started getting errors like:

```
Module::lvsym: Local variable specification {Subscript[e, ap],Subscript[e, am],Subscript[e, is],Subscript[e, sag],\[Theta]$,Subscript[v, entry],tan$,Subscript[ap, new],Subscript[sag, new],Subscript[is, new],Subscript[v, sag],Subscript[\[Phi], ap],x$,y$,z$} contains Subscript[e, ap], which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol.
```

I am not able to understand this error, so I really am clueless as to what part of the code to check. I am able to run the code by copying it line by line to individual cells, but not when it is in a module.
Hope someone can help!
Thanks,
Sid.

[image: Module code]

Comment: `Subscript[e, ap], which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol.` - you can't localize subscripted variables.

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the duplicate, but I did not know this.....

Comment: You are welcome and no worries.

Comment: I just modified the code by changing all subscripts to symbols, and I am getting the desired output. Thanks, Kuba.